# amp-list doesn't show anything

Tags: amazon-s3, amp-html

I'm trying to implement the amp-list component. I've uploaded a json file publicly available on amazon S3 bucket since the content is to be served via https protocol. I've used the example file from the doc (https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/da89bab7c3401f4200d4c58166d5ca062f77e0c0/extensions/amp-list/amp-list.md) and modified it slightly :

```
<html ⚡>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>amp-list examples</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="$SOME_URL" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
    <style>body {opacity: 0}</style><noscript><style>body {opacity: 1}</style></noscript>
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h2> ******* LIST *******</h2>
    <amp-list width=300 height=200 src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/gerswap/test.json">
        <template type="amp-mustache">
        <div>
          <p>text : {{text}}</p>
          <p>url : {{url}}</p>
        </div>
        </template>
    </amp-list>
</body>
</html>
```

Validator says : "AMP validation successful", but nothing is shown in the list.

I've also tried to specifie the template by referencing it's id in an template attribute of amp-list tag as explained in the documnentation (template attribute that references an ID of an existing template element) :

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>amp-list examples</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="$SOME_URL" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
    <style>body {opacity: 0}</style><noscript><style>body {opacity: 1}</style></noscript>
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h2> ******* LIST *******</h2>
    <amp-list template="list" width=300 height=200 src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/gerswap/test.json">

    </amp-list>

    <template id="list" type="amp-mustache">
        <div>
          <p>text : {{text}}</p>
          <p>url : {{url}}</p>
        </div>
    </template>
</body>
</html>
```

List still shows nothing and he validator returns : "DISALLOWED_ATTR template". It seems template attribute is not allowed on amp-list tag...

Maybe I've not correctly understood the documentation...

Any help to make it work would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Ade and thanks for those precisions. I finally managed to make it work. Things that needed to be done :

- As you said : import the amp-list js lib. As far as I understand every AMP extended component needs it's own js lib to be added for it to work, is that correct ?
- As you said also : enable amp-mustache support via experiment. The page you provided only enables non-released components only on cdn.ampproject.org domain. To enable amp-mustache on my own domain, I had to run AMP.toggleExperiment('mustache') in the browser's console as said in the documentation : https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/abf3282cd5670bdf9d2062d5915de97140aee97b/tools/experiments/README.md
- For an unknown reason, I also had to add an credentials="include" attribute on the amp-list tag for it to work in Firefox

Comment: Do you have a public URL or a gist of your amp-list code? I'd like to investigate the Firefox issue.

Comment: I created this gist : https://gist.github.com/jcap-pro/af44351b53cc1684b30a I'll let you experiment, but for me, it's working without any problem in chrome, but not in FF. However, it works on both sides when adding the credentials="include" attribute on the amp-list openning tag

Answer (score 3):

amp-list requires a "src" that is a CORS URL.

Your S3 bucket currently only provides the following headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 181
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Date: Thu, 31 Dec 2015 14:27:34 GMT
ETag: "683081003e1e42bfafcc054540ea60b4"
Last-Modified: Wed, 30 Dec 2015 17:34:34 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
x-amz-id-2: 9/ibtmhzmIdpIA/mjBlZbqDW4BcFYfgH6q52/MCOvMPR0mu9cPCT7acJkiRwh7hcG+BEuYDoJag=
x-amz-request-id: E00AF34C00EDC261
x-amz-version-id: null
```

You need to enable CORS support on your S3 bucket by following the instructions provided here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

Comment: Thanks ade for your answer. I've checked CORS configuration on the bucket. It now seems OK, but the S3 bucket requires the Origin header to be sent in the request for it to consider as à CORS request (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors-troubleshooting.html). Following Curl request returns response with correct CORS header :  curl --request GET https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/gerswap/test.json -H"Origin:http:/example.com" -v. My problem now is that I can't see any XHR request triggered by the browser as I supposed the amp-list component would do. Any idea about that ?

Comment: As you can see from this gist: https://gist.github.com/adewale/7993b7ac919f549eaf27 I've been able to get your page working. 

You need to do the following:
- opt-in to the experiment to enable amp-mustache: https://cdn.ampproject.org/experiments.html
- add the HTML doctype
- import the amp-list Javascript